# How to copy iframe into CK edior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

```
var editordata =  CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();

var itemDetail = '<iframe width="390" height="320" src="' + status.itemDetail.Description + '" style="border: none;"></iframe>';

$scope.report.reportData = editordata + itemDetail ;
```

How can i display iframe into Ck editor

On clicking on a copy button the above function will call .

I am able to display the text contents .
 Whether i need any extra plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a function for that.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml(itemDetail);
```